# If statement doesn't work (Python)

Tags: python, if-statement

When I try to apply this `if` statement,

```
for i in (1,14197):
if (slope[i] <= 5):
    slope[i]=0
```

Nothing gets changed. I read that there might be a problem with the float type of the Dataframe. So one way would be to change the `dtype` and then apply the `if` statement. But isn't there a more elegant way?

Comment: your indentation of `if-statement` is wrong

Comment: Did you try changing the dtype and applying the if statement? Did it work? Can you fix your formatting?

Comment: What is `slope`? What does `for i in (1,14197):` do?

Comment: dind't you want to do something like `for i in xrange(1, 14197):` ?

Comment: yes that was the problem. Thanks. Stupid of me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
for i in range(1,14197):
       if (slope[i] <= 5): 
          slope[i]=0
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are looping with `for`, from 1 to 14197 instead of (1,14197); try `range(1,14197)`
or if it's a list, try it with square brackets `[]` instead of `()`.

Also as @Yousaf pointed out your indentation seems to off.
Or since the slope is a list just loop as:

```
for i in slope:
    if slope[i] <=5:
        slope[i]=0
```

Forgive me if this does not help you. I am just a beginner in Python

Comment: "or if its a list try it with square brackets"[]" instead of "()"" does not matter. `for i in (1,14197):` will just take the values `1` and `14197` because the `tuple` is an iterable. Please format your answer using backticks to surround code or highlight sections of code and click the `{}` button in the editor.